# 100% CPU usage due to system interruption

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I know there are similar questions asked already. But none of them seem to help me.

Since yesterday I have been trying to resolve the problem with my CPU usage going to 100%. I nailed it down to my Keyboard and Mouse. Note that my PC was working fine until yesterday, 20% CPU usage max.

It turns out when I keep my keyboard plugged in, it gets system interruption which leads to 100% CPU usage. But if I un-plug after couple of times, it gets few spikes, and then CPU usage settles down to 20-30%. But if I leave it plugged in for 10-15min and then un-plug, I get BSOD with the page fault exception. I repeated this 3-4 times and I get the same result. I also tried a different keyboard, same result. I tried doing the windows 10 updates and update the keyboard drivers through device manager. It says, its up to date.

If I keep the mouse plugged in and remove the keyboard. The CPU spikes go up to 50%. But if I unplug both. It settles back 20-30% range after few spikes.

I still cannot seem to understand what the problem is. I need to get it fixed asap. Its my bread and butter. And I cannot use my computer without keyboard and a mouse. What should I do?

Comment: I would check for viruses and malware. They could hook into the keyboard driver as a keylogger.

Comment: I thought of that too. So I scanned my PC with Norton Security, and it found nothing.

Comment: yeah... norton security is not really the best scanner. I would scan using Malware Bytes too

Comment: Thanks, let me give that a try.